# how to pass value of array from one function to another in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
int string1()
{
char str[]="something"
}

int string2()
{
//here I need use array str[] from string1
}
```

how can I use array value? Im doing string operations

Comment: im not able to find one

Comment: It's kind of fundamental C stuff.  You can't even begin to do C if you don't know how to pass parameters.  You need to open a book and get the basics down before asking this kind of thing.  `int string2(char str[])` is the declaration and `string2(str)` is the invocation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone has to learn how to use arrays, strings, pointers and functions -- and how to pass arrays and pointers to functions and handle function returns.

When you declare a variable (including an array type), the lifetime for the variable exists only within the scope it is declared unless memory for the variable is allocated dynamically or it is declared as `static` or otherwise has *static storage duration*.

Why? Storage for variables declared within a function is created on the function stack which is destroyed (released for reuse) on the function *return*. (`main()` is itself a function). Now a function can always return a value of its own *type*, but it cannot declare a an array of *type* with *automatic storage* within the function and return a pointer to the array.

```
char str[]="something";    /* violates that rule.... */
```

You have a few options, but they rely on understanding the storage duration for `"something"` and exactly what it is. let's look at what it appears you are attempting to do:

```
/* retuning pointer to string literal */
const char *string1 ()
{
    const char *s = "something";

    return s;
}
```

There are a few subtleties above. First `"something"` is a *string literal* and it has *static storage* duration for the life of the program. So you are assigning the address of `"something"` that is created in read-only memory that will survive the return of `string1`. Since a function can always return it's own type (in this case `const char *` -- chosen for that purpose), you can return the address to `"something"`.

To use `s` in `string2`, you must pass `s` as an argument to `string2`, or assign the return of `string1` to a *global* pointer (discouraged). Since `s` points to read-only memory, you should declare the parameter passed to `string2` as `const char *` to signal it cannot be modified. Something similar to:

```
/* simply use string 's' in string2 */
void string2 (const char *s)
{
    printf ("in string2(), s : %s\n", s);
}
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* retuning pointer to string literal */
const char *string1 ()
{
    const char *s = "something";

    return s;
}

/* simply use string 's' in string2 */
void string2 (const char *s)
{
    printf ("in string2(), s : %s\n", s);
}

int main (void) {

    /* call string 2 passing string1 as the parameter */
    string2 (string1 ());

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/literalreturn
in string2(), s : something
```

**note:** you can only get away with returning `s` in `string1` because of the *string literal* static storage duration. Otherwise, you would need to pass `s` as a parameter to `string1` or dynamically allocate storage for `s` within `string1` and return a pointer to the starting address for the new block of memory.

If you were passing a character array to `string1`, then you would need to do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 32     /* constant for array size */

/* anytime you are passing an array, pass the size. */
char *string1 (char *s, size_t max)
{
    if (max < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient max size.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (strlen (s) < max - 1)
        strcpy (s, "something");

    return s;
}

/* simply use string 's' */
void string2 (const char *s)
{
    printf ("in string2(), s : %s\n", s);
}

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";  /* declare character array of MAXC chars */

    /* call string 2 passing string1 passing array and size */
    string2 (string1 (buf, sizeof buf));

    return 0;
}
```

(Since `s` isn't changed in `string2` it is still properly passed as `const char *s` which allows certain compiler optimizations for your code.)

Look things over. You must understand the subtleties of each example as these concepts underlie much of C. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I tried as per your answer its giving me - warning: passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'char *'
      discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]

Comment: What compiler? I have `gcc` and `cl.exe` and do not get anything similar.

Comment: Your problem is `pch = strtok (str,".");` `strtok` **modifies** `str` -- that is why you get the warning. Make a copy of `str` in modifiable memory and it will go away `:)` (**note**, that code is not in this question...)

Comment: can you tell me how to do that..i did but getting same error

Comment: `char str[] = "your long string";` That creates `str` on the stack. It will be modifiable. Get rid of the `const` -- you want `strtok` to be able to chop the string up. Note the declaration from `man strtok`, e.g. `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);` You must always comply with the function declaration which is looking for `char *`, not `const char *` `:)`

Comment: just warnig now : warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable
      'str' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
  return str;

Comment: Well, you violate the rule I explain when you try and return `str`. It is declared inside `sen_tok`. You have also chopped it up, so the return would be rather meaning less. You need `char *p = strdup (str);` before you call `strtok`, then `return p;` (you will be responsible for freeing it later.)

Comment: You have a number of additional issues you might want to address. See the edit to the answer answering your actual question.

Comment: Sure, I understand the X-Y aspect of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static variable in the function definition block, this has the global storage but limited access scope, when need to access it, just through the function call to get the pointer. Below is the code:

```
char* string1() {
    static char s[64] = "hello"; //this memory has 64 chars

    return s;
}


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    char* s = string1();
    int len = strlen(s);

    printf("len: %d\n", len);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        printf("char at: %d is %c\n", i, s[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
len: 5
char at: 0 is h
char at: 1 is e
char at: 2 is l
char at: 3 is l
char at: 4 is o
```

Comment: instead of printing like this - printf("%s\n", string1()); I need to do some operation on say "s" as this variable we are passing, how to access "s"

Comment: Actually the printf call is one way of access "s", this is the why the content of s is get printed. In C, a string is internally a block of memory in which the content is stored. to access the block of memory, you just need the memory pointer to that memory, string1() returned that pointer.

Comment: i have tried this but its returning full function (string 1 function is executing two times )but I justt want values of s

Comment: for example: char* s = string1(); to read: char c = s[index], to write s[index] = c; make sure index is in the range of this block, which could be get by strlen(s)

Comment: still its returning the full function and not value

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The string from the first function is a local variable and accessing it out of scope leads to undefined behavior. What you could do is allocate the string dynamically and hand control over it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If your `str` is a constant as in

```
char str[]="something";
```

it is a string literal you could simply return `str` which being an array, will decay into base address of the array because it would be in read only memory and will remain there till end of program.
If this is the case the return type of the function should be `char *` like

```
char *string1();
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/ipEuqC).

If the `str` is not so,

```
char str[30];
strcpy(str, "hello");
```

the `str` would be allocated in the stack and it cannot be accessed once control exits the function in which it is declared.

To circumvent this, you could allocate on heap memory like

```
char *string1()
{
    char *str=malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    strcpy(str, "hello");
    return str;
}
```

And don't forget to deallocate the memory once you are done using it.

```
char *p=string1();
printf("\n%s", p);
free(p);
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/NajEzf).